# Only one list element received in request object

Tags: spring, soap, cxf

I am using cxf framework to process soap messages.

The body looks like:

```
<MyRequest>
    <Customers>
        <Customer>customer 1</Customer>
        <Customer>customer 2</Customer>
        <Customer>customer 3</Customer>
    </Customers>
</MyRequest>
```

Using a LoggingInInterceptor I see a correct/complete request. However, I received only one element (customer 3) in the request object List.

Please help!

The xsd looks like..

```
   <xsd:element name="MyRequest">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xsd:element minOccurs="1" ref="Customers"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

    <xsd:element name="Customers" type="CustomersType"/>
    <xsd:complexType name="CustomersType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element ref="ns2:name"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
```

and the generation Request class:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "customers"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "MyRequest")
public class MyRequest {

    @XmlElement(name = "Customers", namespace = "http://schemas.kvk.nl/schemas/myCFXSoapService, required = true)
    protected List<Customer> customers;

    public List<CustomersType> getCustomers() {
        if (custmers == null) {
            customers = new ArrayList<CustomersType>();
        }
        return this.customers;
    }
```

The xsd looks like..

```
<xsd:element name="MyRequest">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xsd:element minOccurs="1" ref="Customers"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

    <xsd:element name="Customers" type="CustomersType"/>
    <xsd:complexType name="CustomersType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element ref="ns2:name"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
```

and the generation Request class:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
        "customers"
    })
    @XmlRootElement(name = "MyRequest")
    public class MyRequest {

        @XmlElement(name = "Customers", namespace = "http://schemas.mycompany.com/schemas/myCFXSoapService, required = true)
        protected List<Customer> customers;

        public List<CustomersType> getCustomers() {
            if (custmers == null) {
                customers = new ArrayList<CustomersType>();
            }
            return this.customers;
        }
```

And finally, the endpoint

`public MyResponse process(final MyRequest request) {
      //some code to handle request
    }`

Comment: Can you share the java code please?

Comment: The xsd looks like..
<xsd:element name="MyRequest">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xsd:element minOccurs="1" ref="Customers"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>